# How does C++ know to use the Class.cpp file?

Tags: c++

I have `main.cpp`, `MyClass.cpp` and `MyClass.h` files.

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "MyClass.h"

int main(){
    MyClass foo(123);
    std::cout << foo.getNumber();
}
```

**MyClass.h**

```
#ifndef MYCLASS_H
#define MYCLASS_H

class MyClass
{
    public:
        MyClass(int n);
        int getNumber();
    private:
        int fav_number;
};

#endif // MYCLASS_H
```

**MyClass.cpp**

```
#include "MyClass.h"

MyClass::MyClass(int n) {
    fav_number = n;
}

MyClass::getNumber(){
    return fav_number;
}
```

Now this program compiles and works fine as a project in CodeBlocks, but if I try to compile main seperately (not in a project) I get `undefined reference to MyClass::MyClass(int)`. I think it is because in `MyClass.h` there is no body for the functions as they're in the `cpp` file.

So my question is: how does this program compile as a project even though `MyClass.cpp` isn't included anywhere in the main or the header?

Comment: The project compiles both .cpp files and links them together.

Comment: read about how c++ compiler works.

Comment: The project file contains a list of all .cpp files, and it orchestrates compiling all of them, then (if compilation succeeds) linking.    When you "compile main separately", you (presumably) only compile `Main.cpp`, but do not compile `MyClass.cpp`.   If you want to do the lot separately, you also need to compile `MyClass.cpp`, and then link the object files (e.g. `Main.o` and `MyClass.o`) together.   One way is to list all the `.cpp` files on the command line, not just `Main.cpp`.

Answer (score 4):

When you add your cpp file to IDE it adds it to compile sources.
Depends on your IDE, for example XCode has section compile sources:

[image]

If you compile in console with g++, you need to type in console:

```
g++ main.cpp MyClass.cpp
```

This means which source files to compile, after that linker should link their main.o MyClass.o files. IDE just do all this stuff by himself.

Answer (score 2):

You compile each `.cpp` file independently (indeed, if you look at your compiler output, you should see `main.o` and `MyClass.o`). The header files simply tell the code that the definitions exist somewhere and after compiling, a linker is used to "link" the two `.o` files together. It is during the linking stage that the definitions are resolved, so when `main.o` refers to code in `MyClass.o`, the linker is what puts these together.

CodeBlocks hides this from you, but its calling out to your compiler and linker to do this. (Actually, if you call `gcc` with all of your `.cpp` files, it will call the linker for you too, but this is simply a convenience and you can do it in multiple steps too. If you are using `gcc` to compile, your linker is usually `ld`)

Answer (score 2):

**You tell it to.**

When using an IDE, the list of files in the "project" determines what list of filenames the IDE sends to the compiler, in a *build command*.

When invoking the build command manually, you have to do that yourself.

For example:

```
g++ -o myprogram main.cpp MyClass.cpp
```

Or:

```
g++ -c main.cpp
g++ -c MyClass.cpp
g++ -o myprogram main.o MyClass.o
```

Obviously add other flags as needed (include paths etc).

Comment: When you execute the command **g++ MyClass.cpp** the compiler will try to find the main procedure so it will produce the error **/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/../../../../lib64/crt1.o: In function `_start':**
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: @RubénColomina: I forgot `-c`.

Answer (score -1):

On **MyClass.cpp** you've forgotten return type specified on its header **MyClass.h** as follows

```
int MyClass::getNumber(){
    return fav_number;
}
```

Comment: While true, that's got nothing to do with the question really.

Comment: don't spam with many answers.  You can edit the previous answer to add extra contents

Comment: In C++ declaration must match definition. Basic stuff.

Answer (score -1):

From a terminal console you must pass to the compiler g++ as argument all the files *.cpp which main depends on otherwise you will have an error as follows:

```
$ g++ main.cpp
/tmp/ccDTbMs5.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x15): undefined reference to `MyClass::MyClass(int)'
main.cpp:(.text+0x21): undefined reference to `MyClass::getNumber()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

As you can see the compiler is trying to look for object code that is not found. When you compile **main.cpp** along with all the **cpp** files corresponding to the includes on your main. In this manner it will work for you as follows:

```
$ g++ main.cpp MyClass.cpp -o myprogram
$ 
$ ./myprogram 
123
```

Option -o change the output program to "myprogram".

More complex situations can be treat using builders such as "Makefile".

In case you do not have the implementation files .cpp for each of your header files .h , you should have instead the binary object code. This should be passed to the g++ accordanly.

```
$ g++ -c MyClass.cpp
$ g++ -c main.cpp
```

The previous lines creates MyClass.o and main.o. Notice that the -c is passed to the compiler to indicate that only compilation will be done. Now you can pass the objects to the compiler as follows linking all of then together:

```
$ g++ -o prog MyClass.o main.o
$ ./prog 
123
```

Comment: I don't understand who is voting me negatively. Obviously this is the right answer well explained and detailed really deep.